# Linear optimization of difference subject to constraints

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I have a vector of values (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7) and i want to create a vector which minimizes a new unknown vector (y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7) such that I can minimize ||x-y||^2. I also want to create this new vector subject to the constraints that x1+x2+x3+x4+x5=x6 and x1+x2+x3+x4=x7. I tried to use constrOptim but I do not think I have the right inputs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Would it be best to come up with a set of values and then use a nls model to predict them? How would I do that?

Thank you!!

Comment: Looks like a nonlinear, but convex optimization problem. This means: there is an efficient solution. But those would need QP / SOCP solvers at best. Of course you can also use just some nonlinear-optimization solver supporting constraints as most of these achieve local-convergence (= global one as problem is convex). But not sure, what kind of optimizers are available @ R. On first look, constrOptim looks like it should be able to handle this when the norm is handles as pure objective. But the nice optimizers would want a user-given gradient.

Comment: @sascha what are QP/SOCP solvers? Also how would I define a gradient for this?

Comment: Quadratic-programming, Second-order cone programming; some forms of convex programming. Popular open-source solvers: ECOS & SCS. But of course the commercial ones like Gurobi, CPLEX and Mosek support this too. Well, gradient-calculation is just doing the math or you use some library doing all that for you (automatic differentiation). But those are probably not that popular @ R.

Comment: Maybe R/constrOptim will use gradient-calcs by finite-differences when you set the gradient to ```NULL```.

Comment: `constraint = function(x)
{
  x1=x[1]
  x2=x[2]
  x3=x[3]
  x4=x[4]
  x5=x[5]
  x6=x[6]
  x7=x[7]
  x6=x1+x2+x3+x4+x5
  x7=x1+x2+x3+x4
}` would this be a valid function to put in constrOptim, if so, what would I then use for the constraint matrix and vector?

Comment: Your constraints do not make sense to me: they only contain data (x). Typically a constraint has some decision variables in them (i.e. y's).

Answer (score 0):

We assume that what the question actually intended was that `y` is known and we want to get  x with the indicated constraints.

Note that nls does not work for zero residual problems and since no data was provided in the question we don't know whether that is the case here or not so we first present two solutions that can handle that and then finally we show an  `nls` for the non-zero residual case.  We use `y` shown below in (1) as our test input for (1) and (2) and it does have zero residuals.  For (3), the `nls` solution, we use a different y which does not lead to zero residuals.

Here are some alternative solutions:

**1) lm** We define `x5_to_x7` which maps the first 5 components of `x` to the entire 7-element vector.  Because `x5_to_x7` is a linear operator it corresponds to a matrix `X` which we form and then use in `lm`:

```
# test data
y <- c(1:5, sum(1:5), sum(1:4)) 

x5_to_x7 <- function(x5) c(x5, sum(x5), sum(x5[1:4]))
X <- apply(diag(5), 1, x5_to_x7)
fm <- lm(y ~ X + 0)
```

giving:

```
coef(fm)
## X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 
##  1  2  3  4  5 

all.equal(x5_to_x7(coef(fm)), y)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) optim** Alternatively we can use `optim` by defining a residual sum of squares function and solve it using `optim` where `y` and `x5_to_x7` are as above:

```
rss <- function(x) sum((y - x5_to_x7(x))^2)
result <- optim(numeric(5), rss, method = "BFGS")
```

giving:

```
> result
$par
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$value
[1] 5.685557e-20

$counts
function gradient 
      18       12 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

> all.equal(x5_to_x7(result$par), y)
[1] TRUE
```

**3) nls** If y were such that the residuals are not zero then it would be possible to use `nls` as suggested in the question.

```
y <- 1:7

fm1 <- lm(y ~ X + 0)
fm2 <- nls(y ~ x5_to_x7(x), start = list(x = numeric(5)))

all.equal(coef(fm1), coef(fm2), check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE
```